# in VB Why (1 = 1) is False

Tags: vb.net

I just came across this piece of code:

```
Dim d As Double

For i = 1 To 10
  d = d + 0.1
Next

MsgBox(d)
MsgBox(d = 1)
MsgBox(1 - d)
```

Can anyone explain me the reason for that? Why `d` is set to `1`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530069/comparing-floating-point-values

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Floating point types and integer types cannot be compared directly, as their binary representations are different.

The result of adding `0.1` ten times as a floating point type may well be a value that is *close* to 1, but not exactly.

When comparing floating point values, you need to use a minimum value by which the values can differ and still be considered the same value (this value is normally known as the epsilon). This value depends on the application.

I suggest reading [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for an in-depth discussion.

---

As for comaring `1` to `1.0` - these are different types so will not compare to each other.

Comment: and why when I print it out its 1? and if so what might be the best way to compare it? thks!

Comment: @Eduardo - How do you print it out?

Comment: I used MsgBox(d) or Console.WriteLine(d)

Comment: @Eduardo - That's because `(1.0).ToString()` returns `"1"`.

Comment: is .toString implicitly been called? when using MsgBox or Console.WriteLine?

Comment: @Eduardo - In both cases. The `double` needs to be converted to a string, so `ToString()` is called on it before outputting it.

Answer (score 3):

.1 (1/10th) is a *repeating fraction* when converted to binary:

> .0001100110011001100110011001100110011.....

It would be like trying to show 1/3 as a decimal: you just can't do it accurately.

Answer (score 2):

This is because a double is always only an approximation of the value and not the exact value itself (like a floating point value). When you need an exact decimal value, instead use a Decimal.

Contrast with:

```
Dim d As Decimal

For i = 1 To 10
    d = d + 0.1
Next

MsgBox(1)
MsgBox(d = 1)
MsgBox(1 - d)
```