# why a double 1.0 its equal to an int 1?

Tags: vb.net

Yesterday I asked why a adding 10 times 0.10 to a double is not equal to int 1;

[in VB Why (1 = 1) is False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449551/in-vb-why-1-1-is-false)

I got an excellent answer. The overview is because:

- Floating point types and integer types cannot be compared directly, as their binary representations are different.
- The result of adding 0.1 ten times as a floating point type may well be a value that is close to 1, but not exactly

I can see the reason why now. However, if I do something like:

```
  Dim d As Double

  For i = 1 To 4
        d = d + 0.25
  Next

  MsgBox(d)  'output 1 
  MsgBox(d = 1) 'True
  MsgBox(1 - d) ' 0
  Console.WriteLine(d) '1
```

In this case I really obtain equality between double 1.0 and int 1. I thought then that double were only approximations so I would expect d to be somehow a value close to 1 as in the original first question. Why is not a good idea to compare directly different data types (in this case double - integer) and why I this time I obtain equality ??

Comment: Try comparison between dim d as double and dim i as Int , this will be false i guess. To make cleaner code type casting is needed so programmer knows what is being assigned to what? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, doubles are usually aproximations. But some numbers work better than others.

Just like decimal numbers: you can write 1/10 exactly (0.1), but not 1/3 (0.33333...).

So it happens that 1/4 can be converted exactly to a binary floating point number, where 1/10 can't be.

**EDIT**
A decimal (floating point) numbers works with powers of 10, so if you can write some number as a combination of 1/10, 1/100, 1/1000 etc (multiples allowed) then you can write that number exactly as a decimal number.

For binary floating point numbers it works the same, only the sequence is 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, 1/16 etc. Plus in computers there is a limit in the precision: some details are just too small to represent exactly.

Comment: You might want to add that any number of the form j/(2^k), where j and k are integers, can be represented exactly in floating point (up to some limit of j and k).

Answer (score 1):

A double can represent integers precisely. However, you can introduce errors a number of ways, especially when using values less than one. For example, this will usually result with x not precisely equal to 1:

```
x = 1
x = x / 3
x = x * 3
```

But in this example, x will be precisely 3

```
x = 3
x = x / 3
x = x * 3
```

If you expect a double to have an integer value, you can use Round(x) to round off precisely to the nearest integer.

```
If Round(x) = 1 Then...
```

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) has a really good explanation of floating point numbers (which is what Double is) and their errors.