# Flutter: Which is more efficient for getting a double from int

Tags: performance, flutter, type-conversion, int, double

Suppose a = 1, and we want to convert it to double
Two Approaches I know:-

1. `double.parse(a.toString())`
2. `a * 1.0`

Which one is more efficient and why?

Also if anyone knows another approach let me know

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Alternative Approaches:

3. `a.toDouble()` [-Oshibka404](https://stackoverflow.com/users/442553/oshibka404)

Comment: Is this useful to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453505/why-a-double-1-0-its-equal-to-an-int-1

Comment: The most canonical way is to use `a.toDouble()`. Conversion of an integer into String followed by parsing it into double seems sub-optimal almost by definition. I suppose, `a*1.0` would do nearly the same as `a.toDouble()` under the hood, but using `toDouble` looks semantically clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this has to do with Complexity.

`double x = a * 1.0;` this runs only once.

`double x = double.parse(a.toString());` technically this runs 2 or more times. it converts to a string first and then convert it to a double. (pop into the double definitions in the flutter framework to learn more.)

so first method is simpler and efficient.